# Understanding the following THz-to-optical conversion scheme

Tags: optics, photon-emission, photonics, rydberg-states

When reading

> Real-time near-field terahertz imaging with atomic optical fluorescence. C. G. Wade, N. Šibalić, N. R. de Melo, J. M. Kondo, C. S. Adams & K. J. Weatherill. [*Nature Photonics* **11**, 40–43,(2017)](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphoton.2016.214), [Nature eprint](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2016.214#citeas).

when explaining the principle of operation of the THz-to-optical conversion scheme it is stated that

> To prevent the creation
> of Rydberg atoms by laser excitation alone, the final laser is detuned
> from the upper Rydberg state, |u〉, by a frequency detuning Δ
> (Fig. 1d). Instead, Rydberg atoms are only created by the Raman
> transition that involves both the laser and THz fields. The transition
> occurs when the THz field is detuned from the transition between
> |u〉 and a final Rydberg state |f〉 by the amount Δ, matching the
> laser detuning. Thus, atoms are excited straight to state |f〉 at
> locations where the THz field and laser beams overlap in space.
> We note that the THz field is not absorbed by the atoms because
> it drives stimulated emission.

as represented in the figure below:

[image]

I understand that the THz field is used to de-excite the electron from an upper state to an energy state |f>.

**Is this energy level transition the stimulated emission mentioned at the end of the quote referenced above?**

**If so, what causes the fluorescence (decay) to take place? Is it also stimulated emission, or is it simply a spontaneous emission due to perhaps the instability of the state |f>?**

**It is also stated that the "interference pattern with nodes and anti-nodes" comes from a reflection of the THz field on itself. The field is traveling in a single direction so is this caused due to the reflection within the cell? How is the fluorescence emitted in a direction perpendicular to the other beams?**

**Why is the detuning necessary? Surely the THz range would be enough to directly lead the excited electron from a state |u> to |f>, no? Would this not still be Raman scattering?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Yes the stimulated transition is from virtual level |u>-$\Delta$ to |f>.

2- Decay from |f> is just spontaneous emission.

3- Yes, within the cell, the THz field is reflected at both quartz walls and creates a standing wave pattern.

4- Fluorescence is emitted in all directions (spontaneous emission)

5- No, Raman means the use of virtual states, and not real states. I would have found it more instructive to have named the virtual state |f>+$\Delta_2$ rather than their |u>-$\Delta_1$, although they want to make a point that they are not exciting a real state, rather a Raman level.

Comment: Obrigado José pela sua ajuda. Thank you so much for your help André.